# How to sort an ArrayList of type Student?

Tags: java

I was reading about sorting lists in java implementation : I found this code about sorting an ArrayList by using a for loop and indexer :

```
public class Exam {

  private String courseCode;
  private ArrayList<Student> anm;

  public Exam(String courseCode) {

    this.courseCode = courseCode;
    anm = new ArrayList<Student>();
  }

  /** Returns a list containing all registered students.
   * The list should be in alphabetical order of names. */
  public ArrayList<Student> getAllStudents() {
    ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
    for (Student student : anm) {
      int i = 0;
      while (i < list.size() && student.getName().compareTo(list.get(i).getName()) > 0) {
        i++;
      }
      list.add(i, student);
    }
    return list;
  }
}
```

I tried to rewrite the getAllStudents() method in this way :

```
public ArrayList<Student> getAllStudents(){
  Collections.sort((List) anm);
  return anm;
}
```

I was forced to do casting in my implementation because I get error if I do not add the casting part.

Is my implementation correct ?

Thanks

Comment: format your code (indentation) before posting it. Read about ordered collections vs sorted collections. Implement tour Comparator if needed. use the relevant library function to get the things sorted or ordered :)

Comment: is my code correct or not ? thanks

Comment: it is unreadable the way you posted it.

Comment: If you just want to know if it's correct: try it out!

Comment: I have a ques . when we declare  `ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();`
does that mean that all elements in `anm = new ArrayList<Student>();` are copied in `list`